# Why does a temporary variable suppress the "type ascription is experimental" error?

Tags: compiler-errors, rust

I am using the Serde JSON crate to deserialize a JSON file to a struct, and one of the properties is optional. When the property is missing a default value (from the command line) it is substituted. This leads me to modifying my code which raises the following error, and was difficult to figure out how to fix it.

My problem is that I'm getting the `type ascription is experimental error` unless I assign the value to a temporary variable, and I don't understand why. I'll show the code and obmit the struct for `Config` as I don't think that part matters.

Here is the code that works:

```rust
    pub fn new(file_name: &str, param_urls: &[String]) -> Result<Config, io::Error> {
        let mut config: Config = Config {
            queue: None
        };
        if Path::new(file_name).exists() {
            let json = read_to_string(file_name)?;
            let c: Config = serde_json::from_str(&json)?;
            config = c;
            // ^^^^^^^ must use temporary c variable
        }
        if config.queue.is_none() {
            config.queue = Some(param_urls.to_vec());
        }
        Ok(Config {
            queue: None
        })
    }
```

The above took me awhile to figure out, and I don't understand why it fixes the error, but here is the original source code that raises the error.

```rust
    pub fn new(file_name: &str, param_urls: &[String]) -> Result<Config, io::Error> {
        let mut config: Config = Config {
            queue: None
        };
        if Path::new(file_name).exists() {
            let json = read_to_string(file_name)?;
            config: Config = serde_json::from_str(&json)?;
            // ^^^^^^^^^^^ ERROR! type ascription is experimental error
        }
        if config.queue.is_none() {
            config.queue = Some(param_urls.to_vec());
        }
        Ok(Config {
            queue: None
        })
    }
```

As a new Rust programmer coming from other languages. I simply don't understand this error, and I've Googled it without really any clear explanation. From my perspective, coming from other languages I see no difference here and don't understand what the problem was that was fixed or why.

Comment: Type ascription is like `config: Config`. It's used when declaring a variable (`let config: Config = ...`, but it's still experimental in most other cases, like reassignment (`config: Config = ...`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand my comment into an answer, type ascription is when the type of a variable is explicitly notated using a colon. An example of this is in your code already: `config: Config`, meaning that `config` has type `Config`. Most of the time, Rust is able to deduce the type of a variable based on its value, so type ascription isn't needed. In fact, except for a few special instances, type ascription isn't even allowed in the language yet (see [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23416)).

The main place where type ascription is allowed right now is when declaring variables. This is when you say something like `let x: u32 = 7;` or `let mut s: String = "abc".to_string();`. Similarly, when defining a struct, you use type ascription to describe its fields:

```
struct Foo {
    bar: Vec<i32>,
    baz: String,
}
```

The other main place that type ascription can (or must) be used is in function and closure arguments. For example

```
fn add_one(x: u64) -> u64 {
    x + 1
}
```

or `let f = |t: String| t + "123"`. With closures, the type of the variable can often be inferred based on how the closure is used, but sometimes it's helpful to the compiler or to readers to explicitly state the type of the arguments.

In your particular case, you're using type ascription for a reassignment operation, which doesn't fall into any of the categories where type ascription is allowed right now. `config: Config = serde_json::from_str(&json)?;` could probably be changed to `config = serde_json::from_str(&json)?;` without any problems, since the compiler already knows that `config` has type `Config`. Reassignment very rarely needs type ascription since it can't change the type of the variable.